# Why does tidyverse still require plyr to load?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

From what I understand, `dplyr` is the successor of `plyr` and as such, the tidyverse doesn't need `plyr` as a dependency. Yet, when I try to load `tidyverse`, I get the following error message:

```r
> library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘plyr’
```

Manually installing `plyr` with `install.package("plyr")` fixes the error and `tidyverse` loads without problems. However, `plyr`functions sometimes mask `dplyr` functions, so I'd prefer to not have `plyr` installed.

Can someone explain to me why `tidyverse` still needs `plyr` and what I can do to load `tidyverse` without it? I checked the documentation of `dplyr` on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) and `plyr` isn't listed as a dependency.

I'm running R version 3.5.2 in RStudio 1.1.463 on 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: also `tidyverse` is a collection of packages, so while `dplyr` might not import `plyr` one of the other packages might.

Comment: It will only mask `dplyr` functions if you `library(plyr)` after you do `library(dplyr)`, just don't load `plyr` into your session and it won't mask functions

Comment: ggplot2 still requires `plyr` and that's part of the `tidyverse`. Maybe you manually updated or changed packages that got the dependencies out of sync. What happens if you do `install.packages("tidyverse")` again? Or what happened the first time you did that? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: @broesel23 No it shouldn't mask the `dplyr` functions. Dependencies are not automatically loaded into your session. If you are ever uncertain if a function is masked you can always refer to a function with the package::function notation to avoid the issue. e.g - `dplyr::mutate()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot2` still imports `plyr` (at least as of version `3.1.0`) and `ggplot2` is part of the tidyverse. Therefore you cannot successfully load the tidyverse with out `plyr`.